# Passing exceptions from one thread back to the main thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception

I have two Threads, Thread A and Thread B.  Thread A starts Thread B, and Thread B keeps running until Thread A tells it to stop.

But, if Thread B throws an exception, I would like to be able to pass the Exception object back to Thread A and re-throw it so that it can be handled by Thread A.

My question is threefold:

1. Is this the correct way to handle exceptions in multi-threaded situations?
2. If so, is there a standardised way of doing this?
3. More broadly, is it possible to call a method to execute on Thread A from Thread B, and how is this done?

It seems to be simple enough if you're creating a Windows Form, because form controls have the BeginInvoke() method.  Similarly, WPF has the Dispatcher object.  Both of these will invoke a method on the thread that the form control/dispatcher was created on.  So I could create a method that looks like this:

```
private void ThrowException(Exception ex)
{
     throw ex;
}
```

And invoke it via the form control or dispatcher.  But in this case, I'm making a console application, so I don't have form controls, and I could only use the dispatcher if I added a reference to WindowsBase.dll, which doesn't seem like it would be the right thing to do if you're not creating a WPF application.

I tried using delegates, but the BeginInvoke method there creates a new thread to execute the method on.  I want to execute the method on Thread A.

Comment: Thread A will need to periodically check to see if there are any Exceptions, how do you plan on doing that?

Comment: That was how I originally wrote it, with a HasException bool.  It worked, but it seemed like a hacky way of doing it.  I was hoping there was some more elegant way of calling back to the main thread.

Comment: You can't just interrupt the main thread whenever you feel like it, Winforms and WPF do it by having a message pump. When it is not executing "your code" it is in a loop looking for new messages to process. Exceptions that get forwarded get put in as a message in the message pump queue to be processed. You will need to start thinking about how you would like to implement a similar functionality in your console program. What is your "main thread" doing, will it ever be "idle"  where you could process a queue?

Comment: Ah, ok.  That actually makes things a lot clearer.  Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, knowing that forms and WPF have the message pump has caused me to re-evaluate how I think my own code _should_ work.  I was thinking that there was probably an elegant solution that I just didn't know about.  Knowing that forms and WPF are actually using a complex workaround makes me feel much more comfortable with the simple boolean flag.